# Using RestKit iOS to POST object to MVC4 webapi not seeing json object

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

trying to call ASP.NET 4 Web API from iOS using RestKit but the serialised json object doesn't get recognised on the server command.
Can anyone help?

obj C class;

```
 #import "NoddyModel.h"
 @synthesize messageId;
 @synthesize message;
 @end
```

(the above are NSStrings)

equiv C# from the mvc services;

```
using Core.MessageDocuments;

namespace WebApi.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class NoddysModel : List<NoddyModel>
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public long NumberOfMessages
        {
            get { return Count; }
        }   
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class NoddyModel
    {
        public NoddyModel(string MessageId, string Message)
        {
            MessageId = MessageId;
            Message = Message;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string MessageId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the mvc command;

```
// POST api/Noddy
[HttpPost]
public MessagesPostResponse Post(NoddyModel noddy)
{
    int count = 999;
    try
    {
        count = noddy.Message.Length + 9000;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        FileStream traceLog = new FileStream("C:\\logs\\Traces.svclog", FileMode.Append);
        TextWriterTraceListener myListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(traceLog);
        Trace.Listeners.Add(myListener);
        myListener.WriteLine("Exception in POST NoddyModel calc count = " + e.Message + " response = " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.ToString());
        Trace.Flush();
        myListener.Flush();
        traceLog.Close();

        return new MessagesPostResponse(false, 0);
    }
    try
    {
        FileStream traceLog = new FileStream("C:\\logs\\Traces.svclog", FileMode.Append);
        TextWriterTraceListener myListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(traceLog);
        Trace.Listeners.Add(myListener);
        myListener.WriteLine("Sending trace information : Noddy = " + noddy);
        Trace.Flush();
        myListener.Flush();
        traceLog.Close();

        return new MessagesPostResponse(true, count);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        FileStream traceLog = new FileStream("C:\\logs\\Traces.svclog", FileMode.Append);
        TextWriterTraceListener myListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(traceLog);
        Trace.Listeners.Add(myListener);
        myListener.WriteLine("Exception in POST NoddyModel = " + e.Message);
        Trace.Flush();
        myListener.Flush();
        traceLog.Close();

        return new MessagesPostResponse(false, 0);
    }
}
```

and the Obj C function;

```
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithString: @"http://ServerX/cirrusdev/api"];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURLString: @"http://ServerX/cirrusdev/api"];
objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;
[objectManager setSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];

RKObjectRouter *dynrouter = [RKObjectRouter new];
[dynrouter routeClass:[NoddyModel class] toResourcePath:@"/messages" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

objectManager.router = dynrouter;


RKObjectMapping* pmsg = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];

[pmsg mapKeyPath: @"MessageId"     toAttribute:@"messageId"    ];
[pmsg mapKeyPath: @"Message"       toAttribute:@"message"      ];

RKObjectMapping* pmsgSerializeMapping = [pmsg inverseMapping];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:pmsgSerializeMapping forClass:[NoddyModel class]];


NoddyModel *msg = [[NoddyModel alloc]init];
msg.messageId =@"abc999";
msg.message = @"Hello Cirrus";

[objectManager postObject:msg delegate:self];
```

and the log from RestKit;

```
> 2012-10-31 15:28:26.851 ELOI[74400:c07] D
> restkit.network:RKClient.m:437 Reachability to host '0.0.0.0'
> determined for client <RKClient: 0x76dda50>, unsuspending queue
> <RKRequestQueue: 0x76ddb90 name=(null) suspended=YES requestCount=1
> loadingCount=0/5> 2012-10-31 15:28:26.851 ELOI[74400:c07] D
> restkit.network:RKRequest.m:437 Sending asynchronous POST request to
> URL `http://ServerX/cirrusdev/api/messages`. 2012-10-31 15:28:26.852
> ELOI[74400:c07] D restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:374 POST or PUT
> request for source object <NoddyModel: 0x7696ba0>, serializing to MIME
> Type application/json for transport... 2012-10-31 15:28:26.853
> ELOI[74400:c07] T restkit.network:RKRequest.m:399 Prepared POST
> URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest
> http://ServerX/cirrusdev/api/messages>'. HTTP Headers: {
>     Accept = "application/json";
>     "Content-Length" = 47;
>     "Content-Type" = "application/json"; }. HTTP Body: {"MessageId":"abc999","Message":"Hello Cirrus"}. 2012-10-31
> 15:28:26.855 ELOI[74400:c07] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:198
> Proceeding with request to <NSURLRequest
> http://ServerX/cirrusdev/api/messages> 2012-10-31 15:28:31.224
> ELOI[74400:c07] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:219 NSHTTPURLResponse
> Status Code: 200 2012-10-31 15:28:31.224 ELOI[74400:c07] D
> restkit.network:RKResponse.m:220 Headers: {
>     "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
>     "Content-Length" = 74;
>     "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
>     Date = "Wed, 31 Oct 2012 15:28:30 GMT";
>     Expires = "-1";
>     Pragma = "no-cache";
>     Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
>     "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
>     "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET"; } 2012-10-31 15:28:31.225 ELOI[74400:c07] T restkit.network:RKResponse.m:231 Read response body:
> {"Successful":false,"Message":"We have received 0
> message(s)","Data":null}
```

PS I manually edited the server name so if its different please ignore

Comment: What debugging have you done on your server? Which block of code is returning from the web service? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi, at the moment its not possible for me to get the server trace file. But what its telling me is that it enters the Post action it tries the following code (first bit)     try
    {
        count = noddy.Message.Length + 9000;
    } but reports that noddy isn't instantiated - so we can see that its not transferred the json data into the object NoddyModel

Comment: Just to inform you that I've solved this now and I'll post a solution tomorrow - when I can be sure of the exact details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were lots of things I needed to try by trial and error - the final thing was that the ASP.NET Web API action couldn't instantiate the Noddy object because it needed a parameterless initializer.